# Prove that the hypotenuse is the longest side in a right triangle. How to write a formal proof for something so obvious?

Tags: trigonometry

From trig text. Given hint: is   $ a^2 + b^2 > a^2 $.

Pythagorean theorem,obviously.

What would be an acceptable proof?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call $a$ the hypotenuse, $b$ the longer leg, and $c$ the other leg.

Then
$$a=\sqrt{b^2+c^2}>\sqrt{b^2}=b$$

There is also an useful result:

> If $a\le b\le c$ are the sides of a triangle and $\angle A$, $\angle B$,
>   $\angle C$ are respectively the opposite angles, then
>   $$\angle A\le \angle B\le\angle C$$

Comment: and vice versa, i.e. $\hat A\le \hat B\le \hat C$ implies $a\le b\le c$, which is what you can use for this problem.